# CSS not completely rendering in ASP.NET Core

Tags: css, asp.net, visual-studio-2015

This is my *_Layout.cshtml* file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html> 
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" asp-href-include="lib/bootstrap/dist/css/*.min.css" />
    <title>SportsStore</title> </head> <body>
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse" role="navigation">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Faen as!!</a>
    </div>
    <div class="row panel">
        <div id="categories" class="col-xs-3">
         <h6>Side items</h6>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-8">
            @RenderBody()
        </div>
    </div> 
  </body>
</html>
```

The end result shoudl look like the first pic, but ends up looking like the second pic. I don't get it, why is the CSS only partially rendering?

[What it should look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NqVVs.png)

[What it looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kCpQh.png)

Answer (score 0):

How someone can expect Bootstrap will automatically make my webpage beautiful without writing single line of css. Right click on your page (ex: SPORTS STORE section) then click on inspect. Check here what's the wrong with the css, why its not binding. Sometimes you need to override bootstrap css by adding an user-defined class to your HTML element and in CSS add important to render properly. For example, here your SPORTS STORE text is not displaying. Add a class to that div or p or span. And in css it will be like,

```
.myTextClassName
{
 color:white !important;
}
.myTopDivClassName
{
 background-color:black !important; 
 border-radius:4px !important;
}
```